# How can I present an array of text inputs to the user representing a RoR Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, simple-form

I have a RoR model (backed by Mongoid) that has an Array field. I am using simple_form and I'd like to present a number of boxes that represent the first few elements of the array.

How can I do this?

I don't need it to be fancy - I don't want to use any Javascript, it is fine if the page is reloaded at any point as long as the data is not lost.

All of the examples i see have the multivalue inputs as a collection or checkboxes - I just want text fields.

Comment: could you post some code? your view ?

Comment: You might want to just normalize that array data (1NF) first. Explode the array so that each value has its own field in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate the array

```
- my_array.each do |a|
  = label_tag a
  = text_field_tag a
```

Comment: How would I create inputs for a bunch of inputs when creating a new object that has no values in my_array yet?

Comment: `my_array = Array.new(5)` replace 5 with however many items you want to start with. This will initialize `my_array` with nils.